# Trying to get a Label's text propery exposed

Tags: c#, grid, properties

I have the following code in one of my Base forms:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI;

namespace ExciteEngine2.MainApplication.BaseUI {

  public partial class BaseCreateForm : BaseForm {

    public BaseCreateForm() {
      InitializeComponent();
      SetupLookAndFeelThings();
      Header = Tag.ToString();
    }

    public void SetupLookAndFeelThings() {
      LabelHeader.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 14.25F, Font.Style, Font.Unit, Font.GdiCharSet);
    }

    protected RadLabel HeaderLabel {
      get {
        return LabelHeader;
      }
      set {
        LabelHeader = value;
      }
    }

    protected String Header {
      get {
        return LabelHeader.Text;
      }
      set {
        LabelHeader.Text = value;
      }
    }

    protected Image HeaderImage { 
      get {
        return LabelHeader.Image;
    } 
      set {
        LabelHeader.Image = value;
    } 
    }

    private void RadButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Close();
    }

  }
}
```

So, I have a couple of properties that allow me to setup Titles and subtitles. But these properties are not visible in the inheriting form's visual designer property grid. I really need to set the base label's image, for example. What can I do to get these properties into the Property grid?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after much Google, I came up with this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ExciteEngine2.MainApplication.BaseUI {

  public partial class BaseCreateForm : BaseForm {

    public BaseCreateForm() {
      InitializeComponent();
      SetupLookAndFeelThings();
    }

    public void SetupLookAndFeelThings() {
      LabelHeader.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 12.25F, Font.Style, Font.Unit, Font.GdiCharSet);
    }

    [Category("Appearance"), DisplayName("HeaderText"), DescriptionAttribute("Text of the form's header."), Browsable(true)]
    public String HeaderText {
      get {
        return LabelHeader.Text;
      }
      set {
        LabelHeader.Text = value;
      }
    }

    [Category("Appearance"), DisplayName("HeaderImage"),  DescriptionAttribute("Image of the form's header."), Browsable(true)]
    public Image HeaderImage {
      get {
        return PictureTitle.Image;
      }
      set {
        PictureTitle.Image = value;
      }
    }

    private void RadButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Close();
    }

  }
}
```

Had to add those Attributes from the ComponentModel.